# On Windows 7, the "Mount Image" Shell Extension Context Menu is missing. How can I add it again?

Tags: shell, context-menu

Through about two hours of searching all I can find a rudimentary methods of the basic file association of .iso to Windows again.

I tried associating with the Windows image burning software and that doesn't seem to change anything neither removing or adding the option to burn a disc image (It was always there).

I tried associating it with explorer but it recursively opens windows explorer then crashes the system.

I am looked at all my shell extension modifications put in by software and I can't figure out what entry on a windows 10 install which has the option, vs a windows 7 install that doesn't - causes the "Mount Image" option to show.

Anyone have an idea without installing something like Alcohol 52%/120%, to restore the "Mount Image" option in the windows explorer shell context menu?

Speaking of Alcohol 52% - that was previously installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 does not have the ability to mount an ISO image by itself.  Third-party software is required for that feature.

Comment: Oh crazy haha, I honestly thought it did!